# What's the difference between linear span and linear transformation?

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations, span

I tried to google both definitions.

For linear span, click http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_span

For linear transformation(wiki takes it as linear map), click http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_map

It seems that linear transformation is a subset of linear span?
Confused by differences between them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A linear span is a subspace of a vector space.  That means it is a subset that is closed under linear combination of its elements.

A linear transformation is a function from one vector space to another that is linear:
    $$L(\alpha x + \beta y) = \alpha L(x) + \beta L(y)$$

Comment: I got your idea.